# Merging Python list of dicts grouped by key value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to merge two dicts on the id. Dict x contains many distinct ids and different row counts per each id. Dict y contains multiple key values, and always has less rows than dict x.

```
x = [{'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2'}] 


 y = [{'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D'}, 
     { 'id':'2', 'laminate': T'}]
```

The output that I want is the following:

```
z = [{'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '1','laminate':'D'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '1','laminate': 'D'},
   {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '1','laminate': 'D'},
   {'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '2','laminate': 'T'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '2','laminate': 'T'},
   {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2','laminate': 'T'},
   {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2','laminate': 'T'}]
```

This is easy to achieve using pandas

```
dfx  = pd.DataFrame(x)
dfy  = pd.DataFrame(y)
pd.merge(dfx,dfy, how ='left', left_on = 'id', right_on = 'id' )
```

But, I am going to apply this using an AWS Lambda function and I don't want to have the overhead of pandas and the output needs to be a dict. I tried the code below which gets me closer, but then i had to add something to find the distinct values of the ID and iterate through them.But,still don't have the output that I need.

```
valuelist = ['1']
def copyf(dictlist, key, valuelist):
      return [d for d in dictlist if d[key] in valuelist]

y1 = copyf(y, 'id', valuelist)
x1 = copyf(x, 'id', valuelist)
y1.append(x1)
```

The above provides this output, which is interesting but not what I need.

```
[{'distance': '2', 'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D'},
 [{'POC1': '2', 'costgroup': '1', 'id': '1', 'post': '5'},
  {'POC1': '1', 'costgroup': '2', 'id': '1', 'post': '4'},
  {'POC1': '5', 'costgroup': '3', 'id': '1', 'post': '2'}]]
```

Comment: Are the `ids` unique in `y`?

Comment: Yes the ids are unique in y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def merge(d1, d2):
    """Given two dicts, merge them into a new dict as a shallow copy."""
    result = d1.copy()
    result.update(d2)
    return result

result = [merge(d1, d2) for d1 in x for d2 in y if d1["id"] == d2["id"]]
print(result)
```

Gives

```
[{'POC1': '2', 'costgroup': '1', 'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D', 'post': '5'},
 {'POC1': '1', 'costgroup': '2', 'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D', 'post': '4'},
 {'POC1': '5', 'costgroup': '3', 'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D', 'post': '2'},
 {'POC1': '2', 'costgroup': '1', 'id': '2', 'laminate': 'T', 'post': '5'},
 {'POC1': '1', 'costgroup': '2', 'id': '2', 'laminate': 'T', 'post': '4'},
 {'POC1': '5', 'costgroup': '3', 'id': '2', 'laminate': 'T', 'post': '2'},
 {'POC1': '5', 'costgroup': '3', 'id': '2', 'laminate': 'T', 'post': '2'}]
```

Merge function from here: [How to merge two Python dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

There's a more concise syntax in Python 3.5 but you're on 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy

x = [{'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '1'},
    {'costgroup': '1', 'POC1': '2', 'post': '5','id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '2', 'POC1': '1', 'post': '4','id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2'},
    {'costgroup': '3', 'POC1': '5', 'post': '2', 'id': '2'}]


y = [{'id': '1', 'laminate': 'D'},
     { 'id':'2', 'laminate': 'T'}
]

#create the id->laminate mapping
m = { d['id']: d['laminate'] for d in y }

#create the final output
z = []
for d in x:
    #make a copy of the dictionary from x so that the input data
    #is not overwritten
    item = dict(d) #copy.deepcopy(d)
    item.update({'laminate': m[d['id']]})
    z.append(item)

print(z)
```

this produces

```
[
 {'laminate': 'D', 'post': '5', 'POC1': '2', 'id': '1', 'costgroup': '1'},
 {'laminate': 'D', 'post': '4', 'POC1': '1', 'id': '1', 'costgroup': '2'},
 {'laminate': 'D', 'post': '2', 'POC1': '5', 'id': '1', 'costgroup': '3'},
 {'laminate': 'T', 'post': '5', 'POC1': '2', 'id': '2', 'costgroup': '1'},
 {'laminate': 'T', 'post': '4', 'POC1': '1', 'id': '2', 'costgroup': '2'},
 {'laminate': 'T', 'post': '2', 'POC1': '5', 'id': '2', 'costgroup': '3'},
 {'laminate': 'T', 'post': '2', 'POC1': '5', 'id': '2', 'costgroup': '3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
z = []
for dx in x:
    for dy in y:
        if dx['id'] == dy['id']:
            z.append(dict(dx.items () + dy.items()))

print z
```